# Como saber el tamaño no vacío de un arreglo de python

Tags: python

Estoy generando un código en Python donde requiero delimitar el valor de un contador por el tamaño que tiene actualmente el arreglo que se ha llenado, es decir creo el arreglo con un tamaño de 5 posiciones, pero si hasta el momento solo se han llenado 1, 2 o 3 posiciones nada más, ¿cómo puedo determinar este tamaño en sí?

El codigo va mas o menos así:

```
def search(country):
        for i in range (**tamaño no vacío del arreglo**):
            if (users_Records[i].origin == country):
                users_Records[i].print_Data(i)
                print("\n")
```

quiero determinar ese tamaño en sí

Comment: Mmmm... no se si sepas la sintaxis o la forma en que trabaja python pero aquí los *arrays* no existen, existen las listas y estas no se declaran con un tamaño específico, simplemente lo creas y vas añadiendo los valores

Comment: Tal como Christian lo menciona: En Python no existen Arrays como tal, sino listas, y como toda lista, se pueden agregar elementos. Cuando te refieres a **elementos no vacíos**, te refieres a algún tipo de valor a los que representes como tal(por ej. '', False, etc)?? Si asi fuera el caso basta con usar [**for in if**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Arrays?

En python no existen los *"arrays"*, en su lugar existen las *listas* definidos de esta forma `[elements]`. A diferencia de otros lenguajes como C o java, python no te pide especificar el tamaño de la lista, esta simplemente se crea y se van añadiendo sus elementos con su método `append()`  existen otros métodos que nos ayudará para realizar distintas operaciones.

## Detalles

Existe una forma de hacer lo que pides, sin embargo tiene sus limitantes, además no es una forma *pythonica* de hacerlo, ya que el no tener que especificar el tamaño ni el tipo de dato nos permite una gran flexibilidad.

Podríamos inicializar una lista con todos sus elementos de esta forma `['','','','','']` pero de esa forma lo tendríamos que hacer manualmente, lo podemos hacer dinámicamente pero con ceros (`0`) utilizando `numpy`. Ejemplo

```py
import numpy as np

n = 5
nums = np.zeros(n)

print(nums)
#salida -> [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Esto nos crea una matriz llena de ceros (`0`) sin embargo esto es un dato de tipo `numpy` lo cual no nos permite hacer las típicas operaciones de listas como `insert()`.

**Cambiando valores**
Algo que definitivamente queras hacer es "*llenar*" la posicion de la lista, aunque ya esta *llena* con el valor `0`. Ejemplo

```py
lista = ['','','']

#cambiamos el valor de la posición 1
lista[1] = "hola"

print(lista)
#salida -> ['','hola','']
```

Eso es el resultado esperado. En python podemos agregar un valor que no sea del mismo tipo por el que esta compuesto la lista. Ejemplo

```py
lista = ['','','']

#esto agrega un valor al final de la lista
lista = lista.append(10)

print(lista)
#salida -> ['','','',10]
```

También podemos reemplazar su valor de la forma `list[i]=value`, incluso cambiando el tipo de dato, lo cual creo que no es posible en otros lenguajes.

```py
lista = ['','','']

lista[0] = 10
print(lista)
#salida -> [10,'','']

lista = [0,0,0]

lista[2] = "hola"
print(lista)
#salida -> [0,0,'hola']
```

---

## Tu problema

Suponiendo que quieres hacerlo lo mas parecido a otro lenguaje como java, C, C++, etc. Crearemos la lista de forma *"dinámica"* haciendo uso del modulo antes mencionado `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

#creamos una matriz de n "ceros" 
n = 4
lista = np.zeros(n)
#tambien se puede crear una matriz bidimensional np.zeros((n,m))
```

Como dije esto nos devuelve un matriz de tipo `numpy`, vamos a convertirla a una lista para poder usar todos sus metodos.

```py
#utilizamos list() para convertir a una lista
lista = list(lista)
```

Si queremos saber cuantos elementos NO vacíos tiene podemos hacerlo con la función `len()` y `count()` (esto sin iterar)

```py
#vamos a tomar como elemento vacío el 0 dado que es un valor falsy
#tambien lo podríamos hacer con vacío ("")

import numpy as np

#creamos una matriz de n "ceros" 
n = 4
lista = np.zeros(n)

#utilizamos list() para convertir a una lista
lista = list(lista)

#cambiamos su valor
lista[1] = "hola"

#obtenemos el tamaño de la lista
tamano = len(lista)

#count recibe como parámetro el elemento a contar
n_ceros = lista.count(0) #le decimos que cuente los ceros (0)

#obtenemos los elementos no vacios
no_vacio = tamano - n_ceros

#imprimimos
print(no_vacio)
#salida -> 1
```

**Usando un ciclo `for`**
Para saber si la lista esta *"vacia"* usando un ciclo `for` nos sera mas facil, dado de que inicializamos la lista con valores *falsy* (`0` o `""`)

**Lista con ceros**

```py
#creamos una lista, ya sea manualmente o con numpy
lista = [0,0,0,0,0]

#reemplazamos el valor
#en el caso de haberlo echo con numpy primero hay que convertirlo a lista con list()
lista[2] = "holas"

#iteramos
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i]: #si el valor es True
        pass #hacemos algo
    else: #si es False (0 o "") 
        pass #hacemos otra cosa
```

**Lista con valores vacíos (`""`)**

```py
#inicializamos la lista
lista = ['','','','']

#reemplazamos un valor 
lista[0] = 3 #reemplazamos por cualquier valor

#iteramos
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if lista[i]: #si el valor es True
        pass #hacemos algo
    else: #si es False (0 o "") 
        pass #hacemos otra cosa
```

Como se puede apreciar el ciclo `for` no cambió, esto debido a que, como dije antes, la lista se inicializo con valores falsy, estos valores son `False`, `0` y `""`. Todo lo que no sea esto será un valor truthy, esto nos permite evaluar la condición como `True` o `False`. Puedes averiguar mas sobre estos valores y como funcionan las listas en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/)

Answer (score 0):

si utilizas len() te retorna la cantidad de elementos que tiene tu array
por ejemplo si tienes

```
array = [23,231,23, '', '']
print(array.len())
salida: 5
```

en tu caso seria

```
for i in range(array.len())
```

y si quieres devolver solo los que contengan un valor podrías usar un if
por ejemplo

```
 for i in range(array.len())
     if i != '':
          #resto de tu codigo
```

aunque es una mala practica tener array con valores definidos, es mejor crearlos y ir llenándolos